# Regex match alert message

Tags: javascript, regex

These may appear multiple times in a large string.  Javascript Regex..

Trying to match both these cases - (the bolded text):  First, ends with ), second ends with the 1st colon.

sometext sometext **Alert Message: \\SERVERNAME: TFTP service is down - no heartbeat. (\\SERVERNAME)**

and this:

IP Address: 1.1.1.1 : **Alert Message: device name is unreachable** : Event Class: /Status/Ping : Site:

This works for 2nd , but not for 1st

```
.match(/Alert Message:.*? :/g)
```

What rx will match both cases?

Comment: Sounds good. What is the question?

Comment: Something like `/Alert Message:(.*?)(\:|\))/` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pipe '|' to indicate an 'or' in a regular expression. Also you can use .*? to skim over unimportant parts of the text to look for sections that are important. Here is an example of both in effect: http://jsfiddle.net/985Kg/

```
var regex = new RegExp('(Alert Message.*?TFTP service is down - no heartbeat.|Alert Message: device name is unreachable)');

alert(regex.test('Alert Message: \\SERVERNAME: TFTP service is down - no heartbeat. (\\SERVERNAME)')); // alerts 'true'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
.match(/Alert Message:/g)
```

This is a lot more general, it might trigger false alarms.